# How to use javascript to show the list of a datalist?

Tags: javascript, datalist

I have a datalist. Its list is empty at the beginning. I use javascript to append the options to that list and want to show the list immediately without clicking it manually. I may need to use javascript code to implement this. Could anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance! By the way, document.getElementById("element").focus();  This doesn't work. It can only move the mouse to the input area but can't show the list. I want to show that list.

Comment: can u share some snippets of what you have done?

Comment: people may need more details to help you. check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

We need to create the "append the options to that list" function.
I think we can create that function based on the behavior of the click, and then run it after the page loads.